# Docker machine can't access internal network (VPN)

Tags: docker, network-programming, unknown-host

First, networking is not my strong suit so I apologize if my questions sounds dumb to those of you with the knows.

I'm running Ubuntu 16.04. I have a docker machine running postgres so that I can recreate a database easily for migrations. I need to pull in a foreign table from a database on my company's *internal network* but my docker machine can't access internal network servers. For example from my ubuntu terminal,

```
ping internal.server.company.com
```

returns with successful pings to the server (it's up). However,

```
docker exec -it ping internal.server.company.com
```

returns with `unknown host`. Also,

```
docker exec -it ping google.com
```

returns with successful pings so I know my docker machine can access the external internet.

Somehow traffic coming from docker can't access the internal network that my host can. Why is this and how can I get my docker machine talking to my internal network?

Comment: Add output of `cat /etc/resolv.conf` from your host OS to the your question

Comment: Yeah you are on the right track. I figured it out. Docker defaults to Google DNS on Ubuntu but has different behavior on mac. https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/default_network/configure-dns/

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue and was able to resolve it by adding the extra host properties to docker-compose file. For example

```
extra_hosts:
    - "internal.server.company.com:172.162.4.111"
```

Comment: This may well be a solution for those using docker-compose but it doesn't quite answer the question here.